# Edit a comment, again and again and again

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, design, comments

I noticed that the edit-dialogue for comments has changed. Now when you click on *edit* a new area will be opened and the comment will be kept so we can see the old version while editing it. This can be a good feature<sup>**1**</sup>

> [image]

BUT while editing **the edit link remains clickable** and we can click it as many times as we want!

Here is the result, a *crazy* thing:

> [image: Screenshot showing four textareas below a comment, the number of characters left available for the comment, three more textareas that also have their own Save button, cancel and help links, and characters left count, and two more textareas below that again with their own buttons, links, and count.]

I think we need somehow <strike>more jQuery</strike> to disable the edit link after the first click or keep the old edit feature where the old comment disappeared while editing.

<sup>1 : maybe this is the main bug and it was not intentional</sup>

Comment: am testing the edit comment here (same issue !)

Comment: When you hit save all the boxes go away. And only the changes in the top box are saved.

Comment: @AndréKool I also like the pyramid logic when you keep clicking .. .at the bottom 1 empty block, above it 2 empty then 3 empty, etc :p

Comment: Hm, that's kinda nifty but also probably a bug

Comment: I think height is at least *one* of the issues - those text boxes end up taking up a lot of vertical space ;).

Comment: Comment box, go home, you're drunk.

Comment: testing the edit box(replicated)

Comment: @usr2564301 yes, probably a reminder in case you missed something while editing ... but it was a simple thought as maybe this is the real bug

Comment: * your issue is not height :)

Comment: @HereticMonkey yes took the screenshot before the edit :p and at the end forget the edit :/

Comment: Seems odd that this would have even changed at all. What was wrong with the old functionality?

Comment: @Clint the DAG team wants to make them more welcoming... or something like that.

Comment: This website is called StackOverflow for a reason. This CommentOverflow is a feature of this website. `status-by-design`.

Comment: What happens if I enter different text in different boxes? (testing...) First box always wins.

Comment: The first box wins the boxing match.

Comment: Wheee! testing... While the top box wins, any of the "Save Edits" buttons will submit the edit

Comment: LOL, almost all of the comments on this question say they have been edited. EDIT: This glitch still happens for me!

Comment: Huh weird, I'll have to try this. Yep, I can reproduce it.

Comment: Have an upvote for noticign this. It is like noticing that your radio flickers if you open the trunk while going backward at 60 mph.

Comment: testing the bug out myself...

Comment: (This is a test.) Edit: test

Comment: They really need to test these changes internally before they push them out to us...

Comment: Not intuitive feature at all since original stays static. Might be more intuitive if original updated in real time while you type. What was wrong with the way it worked before?? The way most edit in place inputs work

Comment: @TylerH why test before deploying if you have tens of thousands of drones testing anyway? :P

Comment: Somebody decided to break comments in general. First the arrows, then the pencil color and now more boxes.

Comment: The whole "feature" is absolutely terrible. This is a clear cut case of breaking something that worked fine, kind of like how awful showing the comment upvote and flag icons everywhere. @MonkeyZeus I'm pretty sure it's the front end dev thinking any of the changes in the past 6 months were good who is drunk.

Comment: @Yunnosch I occasionally got this when clicking Edit once when it first rolled out. That might've inspired this report.

Comment: lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

Comment: It's been 4 days now. How long does it take to sober up?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I think we need to reach 200 upvotes .. go go gooo!

Comment: TemaniAfif, more text boxes seems to be more happiness here. Exactly as @jpmc26 said, comments were fine as they were and I see no reason to change. Rollback to as it was would be good.

Comment: I have a bug fix in the code review queue.  Hopefully it'll get merged tomorrow.

Comment: @AlexL Except that it is present across the network: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313137/repeatedly-clicking-the-edit-button-causes-chaos. (cross-site dupe).

Comment: Previously it was following FCFS (First Come First Serve).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is fixed.

There were two problems at play here.  The first is that we weren't hiding "edit" button, or really the whole comment.

**Backstory:** We are in the process of moving to a structured design system called [Stacks](https://stackoverflow.design) which includes atomic classes like `d-block` and `d-none`.  These classes are meant to act as overrides of component styles and have `!important` on them.  Unfortunately, this doesn't play well with jQuery's `$.fn.css`-based functions, like `$.fn.hide`.

**What happened:** Someone was editing the comment HTML, saw a stray `style="display: block"` on a div, and changed it do `class="d-block"`.  Then when you clicked on "edit", the bravest JavaScript in the world, `jComment.find(" > * > *").not(jForm).hide();`, tried hiding the element and failed, because `!important` is important!

**The fix:** I just reverted that line of code.  A thought out restructuring of the JavaScript is probably more appropriate, but there are already plans to overhaul the comment UI so I'm just going to wait for that to do JavaScript changes.

---

The second problem was why you got so many edit fields, ΣN of them where N is the number of clicks.  Assuming someone is going to break thing again, we've got to fix that.

**What happened:** This problem was less nuanced.  The `comment.edit` function just wasn't idempotent, so calling it multiple times yielded multiple inputs.  The increasing number of fields is because we do two inserts, first we insert the new container, then we insert inputs, and the second insert was matching both the new and the old containers.

**The fix:** I just checked to see if the input was already there before adding it again.

Comment: this a test comment. edit: yes it's fixed! :p

Comment: @TemaniAfif `$('#comment-618685 .comment-body').addClass('d-block')` if you want to recreate the first issue to test the second.

Comment: As a side note : is it really necessary to have the `display:block` initially? it's already a div element so why it's needed?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was just put there as a hint that the style would change, ironically setting up its own demise.

Comment: Ok make sense ;) and yes the second issue seems ok too

Answer (score 52):

I found the bug, and it's related to CSS. The JavaScript code is working fine and I see a `display:none` added to the initial comment in order to hide it, but there is another CSS that is overriding the inline one:

[image]

It seems an *important* issue and we should get rid of that `!important` or add another `!important` to the inline style.

By the way, better avoid `!important`. This is a clear side effect of its use.<sup>**1**</sup>

---

An idea of the fix is to add the class `d-none` to the element instead of adding the inline style. This one appear later in the CSS and it also uses `!important`, thus it will fix the issue.

By the way, I am not sure if the use of `d-block` class there is justified. It seems useless since the element is a `div` and there is no other style changing its display. If we remove it the issue will also get fixed without altering the JavaScript code.

***1***: Of course, I am not here to judge or criticize the great work done by the developers. It's a simple opinion, and I know it's more complex than simply removing an `!important`.

Comment: It's never complex if you use the power of JQuery!

Comment: `!important` is a hack anyway and should never be found in production code.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit well, it's not easy when it comes to library and frameworks, In such cases, we are obliged to use `!important` ... The most common example is the Bootstrap framework where you will find more than 500 `!important` in their CSS. And here they are using the [Stack CSS](https://stackoverflow.design/guidelines/using-stacks) where there is more than 1000 `!important` .. yes it's too much ...

Comment: Just googled that and found that `!important` is not *not important* but rather very important. It should really be `important!` instead. Maybe someone can fix that with some jQuery powers.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I would assume that when you are building a CSS framework for a very particular site, like Stack CSS is doing for SO and the SE network, then you *should* be able to design the CSS a bit better than having to rely on `!important` rules.

Comment: @poke it seems easy said like that but when building a framework you will have many class utilities and for those classes you are obliged to rely on `!important` .. the framework need to be accurate and follow a particular logic because the users of this framework will only rely on adding classes. You can simply check the well known and most used CSS framework (bootstrap) and you will see that there is a plenty of `!important` and it's very hard to avoid them.

Comment: @TemaniAfif It may not be easy, but it's still the right thing to do :) On the topic of Bootstrap, I did notice `!important` in their code during my last project, and was aghast.