# Comment flag notification on the top corner, why?

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, design, comment-flags

Recently I discovered that the notification when we flag comments has changed. There is the common situation where we get "thanks for flagging" and the comment is still visible. In this case everything is fine as we get the notification under the comment.

The other situation is when **the comment is automatically deleted**. In this case the notification is placed on the top right of the screen like shown below:

> [image]

Initially I thought it's a bug **but it's not**. I verified and found that the styles are different in both cases. It seems a feature related to the new comment flag design. For the first case, there is a `position:absolute` used and for the second one a `position:fixed`.

> [image]

Even if it's intentional, it's seems a bit buggy for me to see the notification there so I am wondering why it's done this way? why we don't keep the notification within the comment area, I think it's more intuitive to have it there.

**UDPATE**

Previous questions was dealing with the overlap issue but it's not my concern here. I am more concerned about the position of this notification only in the case where the comment is deleted automatically. I am not reporting this as a bug, I am asking why it's done like this and if it can be changed.

Comment: That FHC is perfect. The Gods of meta will now have mercy on your soul.

Comment: @SamuelLiew it's not a bug, I verified the code and it was made like that ... it's by-design so I am asking why and if it need to be changed

Comment: MSE dupe https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313581/comment-flag-thank-you-note-z-index. Also, report here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313438/please-consider-these-minor-improvements-to-the-new-comment-flagging-modal

Comment: @SamuelLiew no it's not a dupe, that one talk about a  a z-index issue where the notification is in its good place (for both situation) and if you scroll down it will cover the header ... here I am discussing the case where the comment is automatically deleted and only in this case they place the notification in the top corner. The code is not the same for both, for one they used `position:absolute` and for the other `position:fixed`

Comment: @Xufox not an exact duplicate .. my issue is not the overlap, but *why they decided to make it there for the case when the comment is deleted automatically* .. it's not a bug as it's intentional

Comment: Again, this is not a duplicate of the other question. I am not reporting a bug as I know it's not a bug and I am not bothered with the overlay ... my concern is the position/placement of the notification label

Comment: @TemaniAfif Even if the code was written by a human on a day of the week, it's difficult to see how this is not a bug.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit because I checked both cases carefully and the code is completely different .. for the first case they choosed to keep the notification under the comment BUT in case the comment is deleted they are using a complete new code to make the notification on the top ... so the position is not a bug, they made it like is but for us it seems buggy as it's not intuitive to see it there

Comment: To be honest, the right side of the screen IS a popular place to put growls... I mean let me just be nice and rebellious and link to the [jquery example](https://ksylvest.github.io/jquery-growl/).

Comment: @Gimby I agree if it's a generic information related to the whole site, but it's an information related to the comments that are in a particular position within the page ... so doing the action there and getting the notification far from it is a bit buggy OR we should make it there all the time and we will get used to it because actually it behave differently.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Code changes that appear deliberate may not have been intended to have the specific effect you observe. In fact I'd wager that most bugs fall into this category. Do you really think somebody _deliberately_ made this notification appear at the very top-right of the window?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Considering the code I saw, I think yes it's deliberate but let's hope I get a reply ... still got nothing about the comment stuffs :/ https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371327/edit-a-comment-again-and-again-and-again

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**UPDATE**

It is now the Near Future™ and I've rolled out the new notice design.

[image: Screenshot of new notice, centered on the screen with the text "Thanks for flagging! We take your reports seriously."]

Things that stayed the same:

- The notice is a short-lived toast not attached to the comment flagging area. Having it inline with comments broke people's flow.

Things that are different:

- The notice has new styling and is closer to the page content.
- The messaging is now the same for all flag types, making it much shorter for harassment and unwelcoming flag types.
- The notice only appears for 3 seconds.

---

**OLD ANSWER**

This is the default behavior for `StackExchange.helpers.showSuccessMessage`.  We stick a green toast in the top right corner of the screen.  I didn't have a good spot to put the success message when the comment disappeared so I just went with the default behavior.

Incidentally, that's where all "Thank you" messages are going now because my attempt to make the message more contextual came off as annoying and broke workflows. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

In the Near Future™, when I'm not stressing about a deadline, I'll migrate it to use our new [`s-toast`](https://stackoverflow.design/product/components/notices#toast) style.

Comment: What's this "Near Future™" which you talk about? Is it 6-8 weeks?

Comment: Those are cursed numbers. I dare not speak them.

Comment: @BrianNickel you could ask blizzard for a license to use Soon™ if you need an alternative :)

Comment: @BrianNickel Also please consider that positioned elements create new stacking contexts and likely don't need those absurdly high z-index values :-)

Comment: it seems to be fixed today :)